# How to Improve video quality with windows movie maker?

Tags: video, windows-movie-maker

I have filmed series of videos with my iPhone and edited everything with Windows Movie Maker. But now I compared and realized that quality is horrible. Is it possible to increase the quality of the edited videos? Or I would have to start everything all over again?

Comment: Start again. You cannot start with a bad quality video and expect to make a better quality video.

Comment: thanks for the answer! but what I meant is that the video quality decreased once I uploaded it to a movie maker...if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Movie Maker has several options for playback quality. When you export your movie file, click the “Show more choices” underneath “Best quality playback for my computer.”

- Then, click the “Other Settings” radio button and select the desired quality level. Select “High quality video (NTSC)" for high-quality videos.
- Now, click “Next” to save your video with the adjusted quality settings. Be aware, the file size of these videos is usually large.

If this does not improve the quality then you can try starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the resolution, bitrate, and codec information of the source video?

There are mainly 2 reasons for quality degradation in WMM

1. High-resolution source video. Windows Movie Maker can't retain the quality of ultra-high-resolution videos, say 4K.
   I didn't find any better solution than downgrading 4K to HD beforehand.
2. Codec error. If the input codec is not well supported by WMM, it may cause poor-quality playback. Then you can change video to WMM friendly format.
3. The playback is not crispy, but that won't affect the generated file. WMM just processed videos in poor resolution to make the editing process faster.